# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ how to make two parallel consumers will not grab same task at the same time?

Tags: parallel-processing, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have two systems are integrated with RabbitMQ.

---

**BackGround**

Client send multiple request messages from Spring-AMQP outbound-Gateway to RabbitMQExchange, the rabbitmq-**DirectExchange** will use **round-robin** dispatching those messages to Multiple Workers(Those workers are independent located on **different desktops** which will **parallel** running **same worker code** for processing **different messages** from RabbitExchange by use **simpleMessageListner**.

---

**Logic Flow**

Similiar with [Rabbitmq Tutorial multiWorker-DirectExchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html).

> **Client**-----sendRequests **(5tasks)** to ---->**RabbitMQ-DirectExchange**
>
> then **Rabbitmq-DirectExchange**  distribute those  5 tasks to workers
>   **PC1 ( Worker1 )**, **PC2 ( Worker2 )**

---

**ExchangeType & my Bindings**

```html
<!-- rabbit connection factory, rabbit template, and rabbit admin -->
 <rabbit:connection-factory
         id="connectionFactory"
         host="local IP address"
         username="guest"
         password="guest"
         channel-cache-size="10"   /> 

 <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" 
                  connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                  reply-timeout="600000" 
                  exchange="JobRequestDirectExchange"/>

 <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" id="rabbitAdmin" />

 <rabbit:direct-exchange name="taskRequests" 
                         auto-delete="false" 
                         durable="true"  >
     <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="jobRequests" key="request.doTask"   />
     </rabbit:bindings>

 </rabbit:direct-exchange>

 <rabbit:queue name="jobRequests" auto-delete="false" durable="true" />
```

---

**Worker-The consumer Configuration**

```html
<rabbit:listener-container  id="workerContainer" 
        acknowledge="auto"
        prefetch="1"                         
        connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="taskWorker" queue-names="jobRequests" /> 
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

The Worker Class is simple POJO who will process the request and complete task.

---

Use: **RabbitMQ 3.2.2** with **Spring-Integration-Amqp 2.2**

---

**What I expect**

I expect that **Worker1** can receive some of tasks while **Worker2** can pick the rest of tasks ( the other tasks ).

I wish workers can **parallel** together do whole 5 tasks. Each time each worker **only** do one task, after finish will be distribute another tasks one by one. (**rabbit-listner** has been set to **prefetch=1**)

Such as

worker1: t2 t3 t5

worker2: t1 t4

**But**

After lots of runtime-test, sometime it do the task correctly.

**Worker1**------task4 task1

**Worker2**------task3 task2 task5

While sometime it do the **wrong** way like this:

**Worker1**------task4 task1

**Worker2**------task4 task2 task1

Aparently, the task4 and task1 are be picked by worker1 and worker2 sametime.

---

#### Runtime test:

I checked that the **client**  **correctly** send out task1 task2 task3 task4 task5 request message to RabbitExchange. But everytime each worker receive different tasks. There is a common case that may trigger wrong dispathcing.

There are 5tasks **(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)** at RabbitmqExchange, and they will be send to 2 parallel workers **(w1,w2)**.

**w1** got tasks:  **t2 t1 t4**

**w2** got tasks:  **t3 t1**

As Round-Robin dispatch method, w1 and w2 in sequence got tasks.

**w1** got **t2** and **w2** got **t3**.

While **t2** and **t3** running, RabbitmqExchange send **t1** to **w1** and wait for ack from **w1**.

Suppose **t2** spend more time to finish task than **t3** does and **w2** is free when **w1** doing **t1**.

**w2** finish **t3** task will receive RabbitmqExchange dispatched **t1** because **w2** is not busy and RabbitExchange did not receive **t1** finished task ack message.

**My understanding is**

Both **w1** and **w2** are doing same task **t1**. Either one of them once finish **t1** will send back ack to RabbitmqExchange, then RabbitmqExchange will dequeue one task message. As **t1** has been finished **twice**, RabbitmqExchange dequeue one more message that it should. So in this way **t5** message has been dequeued because **t1** has been done twice. Although 5 messages in RabbitmqExchange are acked and dequeue finish. But two workers missing do **t5** and do **t1** twice.

---

#### What should I do that can prevent two parallel workers grab the same message from a same Rabbit queue?

I **tried** auto-ack way, the message are correctly acked. But during the time of server wait for worker's ack, rabbitmq may redispatch the message which is not-acked but already been distributed to another worker.

Also thinking about **synchronized** the sent out messages or **give priority** to sent out messages. But do not have clear vision how to accomplish.

I am grateful to hear any ideas about this problem.Thanks

Comment: You need to explain/show your configuration - exchange type and bindings as well as versions of Rabbit, Spring AMQP. With consumers on a single queue, it's impossible for two consumers to get the same message.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your quick reply. Firstime I encounter this problem, I thought I should use manual ack at worker side to solve some messages been redistribute to other workers's. But after research, I understand that spring-amqp auto-ack did correct acknowldegement. The real problem is during one worker working on the task, RabbitmqBroker may redeliver it to other worker since this task has not been finished (broker not receive ack) and the other worker is free to get job. In this way, two consumers may get the same message.  I am still searching how to solve this problem.

Comment: >>RabbitmqBroker may redeliver it to other worker since this task has not been finished - that is simply not true. The broker will not deliver an un-acked message to another consumer (unless, as @cvbarros says in his answer the first consumer dies or rejects the message), in which case instead of being un-acked, the message is requeued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried long time to work out SpringConfigured-way to implement this feature but failed.

While I come out the workable solution using RabbitMQ Java Client API.

Using Spring-Asynchronous Gateway with QuartzScheduler, it always have problem send message as needed. I guess it has reason for multi-threads sort of.

At the beginning, I thought it because of that the Channel instance may accessed concurrently by multiple threads. In this way the confirms are not handled properly.

> An important caveat to this is that confirms are not handled properly when a Channel is shared between multiple threads. In that scenario, it is therefore important to ensure that the Channel instance is not accessed concurrently by multiple threads.

Above from http://www.rabbitmq.com/javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html

Finally, I decide give up use Spring-way and change back to use RabbitMQ API(Before I use Spring XML configure the gateway/channels, now use RabbitMQ-JavaClient java programming way declare exchange with channels.). And add usage of RabbitMQRPC for asynchronous callback. Now everything works fine for current requirement.

---

So **in summary**, the **final solution** for my requirement is:

- Use **RabbitMQ JAVAClient API** to declare exchange/channels/binding/routingKey. 
  For both client and server side.
- Use **RabbitMQ RPC** for implement asynchronous callback feature.

(I follow RabbitMQ's java tutorial, use this link: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can think that is causing this duplicated messages for your consumers is when a consumer closes the channel before sending an ack message.

In that case, the RabbitMQ broker will requeue the message and set it's **redelivered** flag to **true**. From RabbitMQ [docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html):

> If a message is delivered to a consumer and then requeued (because it was not acknowledged before the consumer connection dropped, for example) then RabbitMQ will set the redelivered flag on it when it is delivered again (whether to the same consumer or a different one). This is a hint that a consumer may have seen this message before (although that's not guaranteed, the message may have made it out of the broker but not into a consumer before the connection dropped). Conversely if the redelivered flag is not set then it is guaranteed that the message has not been seen before. Therefore if a consumer finds it more expensive to deduplicate messages or process them in an idempotent manner, it can do this only for messages with the redelivered flag set.

If when you are testing you close one of the worker processes before sending an ack, or in case they fault, this is very likely to happen. You can try to examine the **redelivered** flag in order to avoid it to be processed again by a different consumer, if that is the case.

Another thing I've noticed is the **prefetch** setting in your consumer configuration. You should set this to a higher value (tune it for your needs) instead of leaving it at just 1. You can learn more about **prefetch** [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @cvbarros. Your answer point out me a good way to research, I have watched the **redelivered** flag, it behaves like you said. But I still can not use Spring-Configured way to work this out. And I do not know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting concurrentConsumers property on the listener container as discussed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#listener-concurrency)?